# Google Merchant error: Not Found

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I have integrate Drupal 7 Site with Google Merchant by using the following instructions:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_gmerchant

but after integration with this when I add the new product using the content type created for Google Merchant. It shows me the following error

```
Google Merchant error: Not Found
```

I googled it but couldn't find any material which can help me. So, I created a view that exports the products in `.txt and .xml` extensions. When I imports these files to Google Merchant account `(Products -> Feeds)` it shows me the error for XML File `XML formatting error`
 and for TXT File `Delimiter detection failed`

Kindly help me to solve these issues and feel free to ask me questions about this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bug report which should be posted in the mentioned module's issue queue.

Comment: If you have worked on this module, kindly let me know the format of files which will be accepted by the Google Merchant. Thanks and I have also report this bug.